# SPO Content Type Inheritance and Copying Content between Lists and Sites

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, content-type

Let's imagine I got 2 sites on SPO as follows:

- /sites/sales
- /sites/projects

Let's also imagine I would have 3 content types (in content type hub) with the following inheritance

- Case

  - Offer

    - Project

**Workflow 1:**

In `/sites/sales` we would have 2 lists based on custom content types. One for `Cases Content Type`, another for `Offers Content Type`. When a Case reaches a certain status, the workflow would `copy` the item to the `Offers` list while the original `Case Item` would remain in the `Cases` list.

**Question 1:**

Since the Cases is based on Case content type whereas Offers list is based on Offer content type (which inherits from Case content type), is it possible to copy such base content type to a list based on a derived content type?

**Workflow 2:**

When the item in the Offer list is marked `approved by client`, the content would be again copied to another list. This time residing on another site `/sites/projects`. The list on that site of course would host items based on `Project` content type which inherits `Offer` content type.

**Question 2:**

Is it possible to copy content between lists located on different sites?

**Question 3:**

Or am I completely thinking this the wrong way?